# Top level entry url not rendering category in url

Tags: routing, category

I have a structure section called products. The entry url format is

```
products{category.productCategory.first().slug}/{slug}
```

However the category never shows in the preview or real world url (real world url gives a 404)

Each product entry only has one category so am puzzled as to why the category doesn't appear in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it's because you're trying to access `productCategory` on `category` instead of the `entry`. When you're setting entry urls you don't need to use the `entry` prefix as it automatically expects this to be the case. So try `products{productCategory.first().slug}/{slug}`

Comment: Seems obvious now - thanks Luke that was it.